# Qt Widget not showing when using std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I am trying to dynamically insert a new QLabel onto my main window. It works fine if I don't use std::unique_ptr and I can see the QLabel being drawn at my window. Why can't I use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent)
{

 setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
 ui.setupUi(this);

 std::unique_ptr<QLabel> shrd_QLabel = make_unique<QLabel>();
 shrd_QLabel->setParent(this);
 shrd_QLabel->setText("test");
 shrd_QLabel->setGeometry(70, 70, 70, 70);
 shrd_QLabel->show();
 //The above doesnt work, however, below example works perfectly

 QLabel * lpQLabel = new QLabel();
 lpQLabel->setParent(this);
 lpQLabel->setText("TEST #2");
 lpQLabel->setGeometry(70, 170, 70, 70);
 lpQLabel->show();
}
```

Comment: You don't really "own" the widget, the window does, and it will handle all life-cycle management of the widget including making sure it's destroyed when you window is destroyed. That's what all this parent-child relationships is about here. Hence no need for the new smart pointers, which have their own and separate life-cycle management that in this case clashes with the one in Qt.

Comment: Please do not use a `QMainWindow`. Simply derive from `QWidget`. A `QMainWindow` provides specific docking functionality - if you don't use it, you don't need `QMainWindow`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has two problems:

```
std::unique_ptr<QLabel> shrd_QLabel = make_unique<QLabel>();  // 1
shrd_QLabel->setParent(this);                                 // 2
```

1. You create a smart pointer that is freed at the end of scope (when constructor for `MainWindow` returns)
2. You assign [ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) of your `QLabel` to `MainWindow`, so your `QLabel` has now two owners - one is `unique_ptr`, and the second is parent`MainWindow`. This is wrong, because both parties assume they are sole owners, and in consequence your `Qlabel` may be freed twice.

Your second example is perfectly valid. It works, and no resources are leaked - your `QLabel` will be deallocated by its parent `MainWindow`. Note, that instead of:

```
QLabel * lpQLabel = new QLabel();
lpQLabel->setParent(this);
```

you could do:

```
QLabel * lpQLabel = new QLabel(this); // lpQLabel is owned by `this`
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `std::unique_ptr`, the object is deleted at the end of the scope, so it's like you did this:

```
QLabel *shrd_QLabel = new QLabel;
shrd_QLabel->setParent(this);
shrd_QLabel->setText("test");
shrd_QLabel->setGeometry(70, 70, 70, 70);
shrd_QLabel->show();
delete shrd_QLabel;
```